# MySQL Trigger running total

Tags: mysql, sql, database-trigger

I have a table, `Transactions1`, with 3 Columns
`ID`,`NetProfit` and `RunningTotal`
I'm trying to create a trigger that automatically updates the `RunningTotal` on new entry as shown below:

```
ID      NetProfit       RunningTotal  
1          100              100  
2           50              150  
3          200              350
```

I have tried the following code but can't seem to get it to work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER RTTrigger BEFORE INSERT ON Transactions1
FOR EACH ROW
set @RT1 := 0;
update Transactions1
set RunningTotal = (@RT1 := @RT1 + 'NetProfit')
order by ID;
```

I get the error:

> Not allowed to return a resultset from a trigger

I have to mention that i'm new to Mysql and PhPMyAdmin:-)
Thanx in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58611191/edit) your question to include what's not working. Is your query giving you an error message, or just incorrect behavior? Once you've added those details, it'll be easier to help :)

Comment: Oh yes, sorry bout that:)... I get an error message: "Not allowed to return a resultset from a trigger"

Comment: You cannot action the table which fired the trigger..You can set NEW. values in a before insert trigger and I would expect to see reference to NEW. values in a before insert trigger.BUT your update doesn't make a lot of sense without context. please add table definition sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply:-)... I'm trying to follow along, but i'm quite new with SQL:-)

Comment: What i'm trying to do is: I have a "Net Profit" on every new row and what i would like to do is have a column which should be a cumulative total of netprofit... 

Like This

ID 1 = 1 ------ Net Profit = 100 ------ Running Total = 100
ID 2 = 2 ------ Net Profit = 150 ------ Running Total = 250
ID 2 = 2 ------ Net Profit = 350 ------ Running Total = 600